# Getting window.devicePixelRatio in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I'm doing some worth with canvas, and I need to get the following values:

```
// This one:
window.devicePixelRatio

// and any one of:
Context2d.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio ||
Context2d.mozBackingStorePixelRatio ||
Context2d.msBackingStorePixelRatio ||
Context2d.oBackingStorePixelRatio ||
Context2d.backingStorePixelRatio
```

These don't seem to be available in the GWT equivalent classes (I think) - do I have to create a native method to grab them or is there some better way of doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right they are not available in core gwt classes so you have to implement them using jsni.

Another option is to use [elemental](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/elemental) which is included in gwt-2.5.0 and have those methods, but elemental is only implemented for webkit.

[edited]

You can create your own context2 class with the jsni methods you need and use overlay casting to convert a gwt context2 to your class:

```
  public class MyContext2 extends Context2d {
    public final native float webkitBackingStorePixelRatio() /*-{
      return this.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio;
    }-*/;    
  }

  Context2d ctx = ...;

  // call your method through the cast()
  float ratio = ctx.<MyContext2>cast().webkitBackingStorePixelRatio();

  // or convert the context to your class
  MyContext2 mctx = ctx.cast();
  float ratio = mctx.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio();
```

Comment: Do you know how to write a jsni method for the Context2d.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio attribute? The Window.devicePixelRatio one is straightforward. But I don't know how to do the other one because I already have a GWT Canvas2d object.